# How can I store latitude and longitude without PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, spatial

I know there are similar questions on here that have been answered but unfortunately none of them work for me. I am hacking my way through creating a page which will display multiple locations on a map. I am using HTML 5 mapping plus Google maps. I have converted the addresses I have, into long/lat and they are stored in a CSV file along with other attributes.

I have tried storing as point, character varying and number as well as trying to create my own definition but have had no success. The table already exists and I just need to add these additional columns. I would rather not use PostGIS since that feels like adding in an additional level of complexity which I could well do without.

So what do you suggest?

Comment: I would say if you are doing a lot of GIS processing then adding PostGIS will actually *remove* some complexity. But even if you only use the PostGIS data types, I don't see how that adds "additional complexity". You install it once and then you are done. Btw: what exactly was the problem when using the `point` data type?

Answer (score 12):

The simplest solution without PostGIS would be to store lat/long as two number columns.
[`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) for exact precision.
[`double precision`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) or even just [`real`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) if you don't need the precision.

I see no reason why the data type [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6718) shouldn't work as well. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6718):

> Points are the fundamental two-dimensional building block for
>   geometric types. Values of type `point` are specified using either of
>   the following syntaxes:
>
> ```
> ( x , y )
>   x , y
> ```
>
> where `x` and `y` are the respective coordinates, as floating-point
>   numbers.

Related:

- [Which data type for latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8150944/939860)

Answer (score 4):

> I would rather not use PostGIS since that feels like adding in an additional level of complexity which I could well do without.

That's pretty silly. Firstly, latitude, and longitude without an SRS ID say nothing of where those points are. Are they project or unprojected? Where is `POINT( 0 0 )`? Are you addressing from East or West as negative?

Just use PostGIS. It's not complex. It does more of your problem so you don't have to.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( geog geography(POINT, 4326) );
INSERT INTO foo (geog) ( ST_MakePoint(0,0) );
```

## Comparison with geometric [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-geometric.html)

Even in the simple case,

- a point in PostGIS can be exported to GeoJSON `ST_AsGeoJSON`, or a slew of export formats
- can be aggregated into a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`
- can be aggregated into a line that connects all points.
- can be aggregated into a polygon (`ST_ConvexHull`)
- can have the distance calculated between points using `ST_Distance`
- can be reprojected to other reference systems
- can be be indexed

  - is subject to KNN queries on index (find nearest point) with `<=>`
  - find all points-of-interest within X-range `ST_DWithin`